# How do I import one specific NPM module from Google cloud artifact registry, others from normal NPM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deno, google-artifact-registry

I want to write a Deno-based app that uses some NPM modules. Most of them will come from the normal NPM registry, and this works fine with the `npm:` prefix. However, one specific module scope is mapped to a (publicly available) Google artifact registry I control - for regular Node-based projects this mapping is done in a `.npmrc`-file. I have experimented with various settings but not found the right way to do it yet. For example, maybe I could add an import mapping that sort of matches the `.npmrc` with:

```
  "imports": {
    "npm:@example/mymodule": "https://europe-west1-npm.pkg.dev/mymodule/mymodule/"
  }
```

and simply do

```
import exampleModule from "npm:@example/mymodule";
```

It throws a `Module not found` error.

Perhaps I could map to the zipped file for a specific version using something like this in the deno.jsonc - file?

```
  "imports": {
    "npm:@example/mymodule": "https://europe-west1-npm.pkg.dev/mymodule/mymodule//@example/mymodule/-/@example/mymodule-1.0.17.tgz"
  }
```

Error is now `invalid utf-8 sequence of 1 bytes from index 1`.

What is the right way to do this, assuming there is one?

Comment: In some quick searches, I don't find this discussed — I don't think Deno provides support for alternative npm registries at this time. Conventional approaches would be to (1) use an [npm CDN](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/node/cdns) or to (2) download and decompress the tarball to your filesystem, and create the desired import map entries (basically manually replicate what [`deno vendor`](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/tools/vendor) does for remote ES module resources).